# what is the meaning of this syntax

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

The following code compiles. But if I write the code to call the method `test` using `jar` it is giving me a compilation error. What is really happening here.

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  void test() {
    cout << "working" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  A foo;
  A jar();
}
```

Comment: That's not a variable declaration.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 A jar();
```

declares a function named `jar` without any parameters, and return type is object of class `A`.

You cannot declare a function inside `main`, therefore, you got the error.

Comment: It's not really the MVP (`SomeType var(SomeClass());`), but close enough. You can declare the function, but you can't use it like an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to declare a function pointer named `ptr` you should declare it like that:

```
A (*ptr)(void);
```